# Function returns before completing the code in another file in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, async-await

I have a function which is in model, and i call that model from my controller but before completing the execution of the code in model, it comes back to controller and after completing the code in controller again it comes back  to model to execute the remaining code. In below  code whwn i call a function od model, it executes line a and continues upto line b, but after line b, it will not go to line c instead it comes back to controller and executes line "vara = 0;" and further codes of controller and after completing execution of all the codes again it will comes back model and executes line c and further codes, please give me some suggestions?

```
*Controller*
 const invoicePdfResp = await PdfModel.generateInvoicePdf(invoiceId);
 var a = 0;

*Model*
exports.generateInvoicePdf = async function(invoiceId){

a.    await Invoice.findById(invoiceId, async function(err, doc) {
        if(!err && doc!=null){
            var title = doc.title;
            var description = doc.description;
            var interestAmount = doc.interest;
            var grandTotalAmount = doc.totalAmount;
            var totalAmount = grandTotalAmount - interestAmount;
            var userName = '';
            var itemList = [];
b.            await User.findById(doc.created_by, async function(err1, doc1) {
c.              if(doc1!=null){
                    userName = doc1.firstname + " " + doc1.lastname;
                    InvoiceItem.find({'invoice_id':doc.id}, async function(err2, doc2) {
                        if(doc1.length!=0){
                            itemList = doc2;
                            const pdfDoc = new PDFDocument({margin: 25});
                            //some pdf generation code
                            pdfDoc.end();
                        }
                    })
                }else{
                    response = {
                        'message':'failed'
                    }
                    res.send(response);
                }
            });
        }else{
            response = {
                'message':'failed'
            }
            res.send(response);
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: You are mixing `async/await` and callbacks, that may be culprit.

Comment: But if i have to use await, async is a must.

Comment: Yes, but you should do `const doc = await Invoice.findById(invoiceId)` then ^^.